# Does the SERIALIZE instruction prevent speculative execution?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, speculative-execution

Recently came across the [SERIALIZE](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/serialize) instruction.

> Serializes instruction execution. Before the next instruction is
> fetched and executed, the SERIALIZE instruction ensures that all
> modifications to flags, registers, and memory by previous instructions
> are completed, draining all buffered writes to memory.

Here's a sample masm64 program that has a `Secret Key`. Before accessing the key, it surrounds the sensitive code with `SERIALIZE` calls to hopefully prevent any kind of Speculative Execution.

```
option casemap:none

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib libcmt.lib

.data
sensitiveData db "My Secret Key", 0

.code
main proc
    SERIALIZE                     
    lea     eax, [sensitiveData]
    SERIALIZE                     
    ret
main endp

end
```

**Question**

Can `SERIALIZE` be used to mitigate [Speculative Execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) vulnerabilities such as [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability))?

**Update**

Just found this article that explains this new instruction.

[Linux Kernel Prepping To Make Use Of Intel's New SERIALIZE Instruction](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-SERIALIZE-Sync-Core)

> ... a [patch series](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200727043132.15082-1-ricardo.neri-calderon@linux.intel.com/) was sent out by an Intel Linux engineer for making
> use of the Intel SERIALIZE instruction within the kernel's sync_core()
> function. Linux's sync_core function is called for stopping the
> speculative execution and prefetching of modified code. ...

Comment: Reading the description, it might.  Note that it'll also be really slow to use this instruction.

Comment: `lea` does not access the key. Anyway, an exploit might use a vulnerability elsewhere to access secret data. It does not have to be in the code that normally processes the secret.

Comment: Yes, `serialize` will prevent speculative execution. It's just like `cpuid` but without the burden of clobbering most of the GP registers. In fact `serialize` can even protect against side-channel attacks that rely on the uop cache (just like `cpuid` but unlike `lfence`) because it also stalls the front-end.